# How to change the color of the CJuiProgressBar?

Tags: yii, progress-bar

I want to change the color of the CJuiProgressBar depending on the value, let's say Green for less than 60%, yellow for 61% to 80% and Red for 81% or above.

Any ideas on how to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the theme of your `CJuiProgressBar` according to your value (I'm supposing you are going to do this in PHP instead of in Javascript).

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiProgressBar',array(
    'value'=>75,
    'cssFile' => 'themeRed.css',
    'theme'   => 'red',
));
```

From [Yii documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CJuiWidget#cssFile-detail):

> The theme CSS file name. Defaults to 'jquery-ui.css'. Note the file
>   must exist under the URL specified by themeUrl/theme. If you need to
>   include multiple theme CSS files (e.g. during development, you want to
>   include individual plugin CSS files), you may set this property as an
>   array of the CSS file names. This property can also be set as false,
>   which means the widget will not include any theme CSS file, and it is
>   your responsibility to explicitly include it somewhere else.

[Progress Bar Documentation from jQuery UI](http://api.jqueryui.com/progressbar/)